# Can JavaScript tell whether Tracking Protection is enabled in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-analytics

So I've decided to try Google Optimize for conversion testing and, like other tools, it swaps stuff around via JavaScript.

To avoid flickery behaviour Google recommends adding a script that sets opacity:0; for the entire page until either

- a callback from Google Analytics arrives to signal that page modifications have been completed
- a timeout is hit (4000ms default).

The callback **relies on analytics.js** to be executed.

With tracking protection enabled in Firefox, Google Analytics is blocked and thus the callback never arrives. Hence users of the tracking protection feature are greeted with 4000ms of greyscreen on every pageload, waiting for a callback from GA that will never come. This is clearly far from desirable.

Now I'd like to remove the greyscreen altogether for users who have Analytics blocked. But I have not had any luck in coming up with a conditional that can evaluate whether the browser **allows** Analytics to be loaded. Is there any way to tell this in advance?

The solution could not be based on checking for code from analytics.js or on having a timeout, since those are exactly the things I'm trying to circumvent.

Comment: "But I have not had any luck in coming up with a conditional that can evaluate whether the browser allows Analytics to be loaded. Is there any way to tell this in advance?" Would the ability to do a callback if it fails to load be enough?

Comment: That would depend on how quickly the callback is fired. Optimally the entire thing would be completed before the rest of the page loads.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to tell this in advance?

Kind of, but it's awkward. You need to make a honeypot request to a domain blocked by Tracking Protection, and see if it returns an exception or empty response body (some blockers are smart enough to return 'empty' ad/analytics scripts). If it does, you can tell 'early' that the browser isn't letting through certain requests, and short circuit your render delay.

You will need to dispatch this request as early as possible, so that other requests (images, ad assets, scripts) don't consume the HTTP resource pool and lock your request from completing (or failing) in a timely manner.

You can also test for generic adblockers in a synchronous fashion by creating an element with a class like '.advert', inserting it into the DOM, and seeing if it was given display-none in a frame's time. This is still asynchronous, but it'll be a lot more reliable.

It's still not ideal, though, and you'll probably get false positives now and then. A/B tests that involve DOM changes should be run from the server side, not awkward sideloaded scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect whether Google Analytics was blocked or otherwise unavailable after the fact, by slightly modifying the tracking snippet you add to your pages to add an error handler.

In the snippet, after `a.async=1;`, add `a.onerror=i.gaFailedToLoad;` or similar. That will cause the function `window.gaFailedToLoad` to run the moment Google Analytics is completely blocked.

This will not run on more advanced blockers such as uBlock Origin, which replaces the analytics request with a neutered version.